# Creating Random Column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking to create a two column table, something looking like this:

```
a   b
1 | 5
1 | 3
1 | 1
1 | 2
1 | 4
2 | 3
2 | 4
2 | 1 
2 | 2
2 | 5
```

The first column is a consecutive sequence of numbers with repeated numbers as shown. The second column is a random series of unique numbers for however many repeated numbers there are.

I have searched hard to find a way to do this. So far I can come up with unique random numbers by doing generate_series(1,5) ORDER BY RANDOM(). But this only creates it once. And also doesn't create the whole table that I am looking for.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  What data are you starting with?  The order of the rows does not matter, so both 1 and 2 have equivalent values in the second column.  There is a difference between "random value" and "random permutation".

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm look to produce the table I have given in the question. I guess I mean random permutation

Comment: `select * from generate_series(1,3) as a, generate_series(1,5) as b order by a, random();`?

Comment: @Abelisto Yes that's it.

Comment: @Abelisto Can you look at my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42846619/setting-column-to-null-and-joining-in-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

One method is to bypass the optimization so `random()` runs for every row.  A correlation clause has this effect:

```
with v as (
      select generate_series(1, 5) as x
     ),
     t as (
      select generate_series(1, 20) y
     )
select *
from t, lateral
     (select v.x
      from v
      where t.y is not null
      order by random()
      limit 1
     ) x;
```

Comment: But this doesn't have distinct random numbers